# How to fix type checking when using this.store.findRecod

Tags: typescript, ember.js, ember-data

In my ember.js project, I type check javascript files with Typescript and the [checkJs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-checking-javascript-files.html#supported-jsdoc) option.

Here is a simple `route.js` file example

```js
import Route from '@ember/routing/route';

export default class UsersRoute extends Route {
  model() {
    return this.store.findAll('user');
  }

}
```

With this code, I get the following Typescript error

```
route.js:5:31 - error TS2345: Argument of type '"user"' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.

5     return this.store.findAll('user');
                                ~~~~~~
```

The ember-data type definitions are provided by the @types/ember-data package, and here is the [findAll definition](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/bcff64de551f279fa30469e7a236c2ffc9547c30/types/ember-data/index.d.ts#L1130)

```
findAll<K extends keyof ModelRegistry>(
    modelName: K,
    options?: {
        reload?: boolean;
        backgroundReload?: boolean;
        include?: string;
        adapterOptions?: any;
    }
): PromiseArray<ModelRegistry[K]>;
```

This is how far I could go while investigating how `findAll` was defined.

In theory, `this.store.findAll('user');` is valid, but what should I do to fix this Typescript error?

Comment: you'll need to add user to the ModelRegistry in a type definitions file ;)

Comment: (check the TS Models for an example)

Comment: Do you may miss to declare your models on `ModelRegistry`? Double-check your models against the [Ember CLI TypeScript docs for Ember Data](https://typed-ember.github.io/ember-cli-typescript/docs/ts-guide/using-ts-effectively#ember-data-lookups).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To understand what's happening I recommend reading [this section of the ember-cli-typescript docs](https://typed-ember.github.io/ember-cli-typescript/versions/master/docs/ts-guide/using-ts-effectively#ember-data-lookups). The gist is that the types supplied for Ember do some extra work to make it so that when you type `this.findRecord('person', 1)`, the thing you get back is a `Person` (e.g. the `DS.Model` you've defined). To make that work, the types define a "registry"—a mapping between the string name and the type to return. That "registry" being empty is the problem you're seeing in the types.

The default configuration with ember-cli-typescript makes this "just work", by setting up the `paths` key in `tsconfig.json` to include `"*": "types/*"` and including this file at `<your app directory>/types/ember-data/types/registries/model.d.ts`:

```
/**
 * Catch-all for ember-data.
 */
export default interface ModelRegistry {
  [key: string]: any;
}
```

That makes all string lookups for models "work" by just making the type be `any`.

If you want to actually *define* types, you'll need to create a `user.d.ts` file located right next to the `user.js` which exports the model type *and* which includes this:

```
declare module 'ember-data/types/registries/model' {
  export default interface ModelRegistry {
    'user': User;
  }
}
```

Running `ember generate ember-cli-typescript` if you're already using it will update these things for you. You can also manually create that file with those contents and set up the `paths` mapping (and you may want to add the other paths mappings from [the default blueprint](https://github.com/typed-ember/ember-cli-typescript/blob/master/blueprint-files/ember-cli-typescript/tsconfig.json) as well).